# Vertical alignment of elements

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code with an image and author description:

```
<div class="blog-article-author">
    <div class="blog-article-author-details">
        <div class="post-author-image-desc">
            <img alt="" src="1.jpg" height="75" width="75">                             
        </div>
        <h6><a href="#" title="Posts by admin">admin</a></h6>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have CSS:

```
.blog-article-author {
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    padding: 20px 30px 35px;
    margin: 75px 0;
}

.blog-article-author-details {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.post-author-image-desc {
    text-align: center;
}

.page-content .blog-article img {
    float: left;
}

.blog-article-author-details h6 {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

I want to align the description vertically.

```
image

image       description here 

image
```

I tried to use padding and margin. But I don't know the length of `<p>`. So I need to correct my CSS.

Comment: Did u try display:block  in   <div class="post-author-image-desc">

Comment: Your schematic shows "description here" next to the 2nd of 3 images.  Is that the `<p>Lorum Ipsum</p>` in your HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is really difficult to understand, but as far as I can understand, the following code will help you.

```css
.blog-article-author {
    border: solid 1px #DDD;
    padding: 10px;
}

.post-author-image-desc {
   display:table;
}

.post-author-image-desc img {
    float:left;
}

.post-author-image-desc h6 {
    margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
}

.post-author-image-desc p {
    margin: 0px;
}

.post-author-image-desc .post-full-desc {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-article-author">
  <div class="blog-article-author-details">
    <div class="post-author-image-desc">
      <img alt="" src="http://www.sheffield.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/placeholder.png" height="100" width="100">
        <div class="post-full-desc">
          <h6>Admin</h6>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei vix ubique meliore. Vivendum honestatis mea ex.</p>
        </div>
      <div class="clear">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property
    vertical-align: text-top;

Or where ever you want it to align with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've completely understood you, but do you mean display elements in a line under the image? If that's what you want you could move the description inside the div that contains the image. See snippet below:

```css
.blog-article-author {
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    padding: 20px 30px 35px;
    margin: 75px 0;
}

.blog-article-author-details {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.post-author-image-desc {
    text-align: center;
}

.page-content .blog-article img {
    float: left;
}

.blog-article-author-details h6 {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-article-author">
    <div class="blog-article-author-details">
        <div class="post-author-image-desc">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" height="75" width="75">                             <h6><a href="#" title="Posts by admin">admin</a></h6>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the css property `vertical-align` will help?

For example: `vertical-align:middle`